# Non-Euclidean geometry which is the union of Euclidean geometries?

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

While reading on Wikipedia about non-Euclidean geometry, I tried to think of very simple geometries that invalidate Euclid's first postulate. This lead me to the following question. I do not have any background in geometry beyond high school math. I am asking out of curiosity.

Suppose that $P_a$  and $P_b$ are two disjoint Euclidean planes, and that we do not make any further assumptions about their relation (in particular, I do not assume that these two planes are embedded in a three dimensional Euclidean space). By disjoint I mean that there is no point which is both on $P_a$ and $P_b$.

Both $P_a$ and $P_b$ satisfy all the axioms of Euclidean geometry when considered in isolation. For each, we have the usual definitions of points, lines, angles etc.  I was wondering if it make any sense to treat the union of $P_a$ and $P_b$ as a non-Euclidean geometry. In such a union, I assume that a point (line) is in the union iff it is a point (line) in $P_a$ or a point (line) in $P_b$.

Now consider the postulates of Euclidean geometry:

- If $p_1$ is a point on $P_a$ and $p_2$ is a point on $P_b$, then there is no line going through $p_1$ and $p_2$. This invalidates Euclid's first axiom ("*To draw a straight line from any point to any point*", [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry#Axioms))
- Euclid's second and fourth axioms remain valid, as far as I can see.
- Playfair's axiom (*In a plane, given a line and a point not on it, at most one line parallel to the given line can be drawn through the point.* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair%27s_axiom)) is false, if we take the union of $P_a$ and $P_b$ to be a plane. For if you take a line and a point not on it from $P_a$, every line in $P_b$ is parallel to it (where parallel means no intersection at any point). Therefore, there are infinitely many lines parallel to the line on $P_a$.  On the other hand, if the union is not a plane, then Playfair's axiom is valid.

**My Question:**

> Does such union geometry make any sense? If no, are there any inconsistencies or abuse of terminology that I am missing? If yes, what is the name of such non-Euclidean geometry and what is its relation to other non-Euclidean geometries?

I think I am confused because it is unclear to me what is the "right way" to generalize concepts from Euclidean geometry, such as the concepts of a plane and parallel lines.

We can ask similar questions about more complicated unions, such as the union of two three dimensional Euclidean spaces, or the union of spherical geometry with a Euclidean plane.

Comment: It's not enough to provide a point set, you have to show that the other postulates make sense and are satisfied.  Suppose I take one point on each plane...how do you define the line between them?

Comment: Personally, I've always thought Spherical Geometry was the best way to get a non-Euclidean example.  True, you have to worry that the line connecting two antipodal points is not unique, but you can avoid that by identifying points with their anti-podes.  Seems a lot simpler than the Hyperbolic model.

Comment: It is a valid geometry, just not a particularly interesting one. Historically, the name "non-Euclidean" is reserved for geometries violating just the 5th postulate and not the others. As for the "right" way to generalize the Euclidean geometries, there is no generally-agreed upon answer, but in modern geometry one tries to keep the 1st and 2nd postulates.

Comment: It's not so much that there's a "right way" to go about developing non-Euclidean geometries (or any other aspect of mathematics, really), but some ways turn out to be more "fruitful" than others. Your union of Euclidean planes successfully breaks Euclid's First Postulate. *Congratulations!* But: *Now what?* If you can provide an "interesting" way of *doing geometry* on that union, great! Otherwise, the value of that example is in showing the First Postulate's wisdom for avoiding "unhelpful" configurations. (Continued)

Comment: (Continuing) Of course, perceptions of fruitful-ness, interesting-ness, and (un)helpful-ness are all subjective ... and *subject to change*. It's worth noting that (what we now know as) hyperbolic geometry was initially resisted by many in the mathematical community as it included such utter *absurdities* as the lack of a constant angle-sum for triangles. *How "helpful" could such a geometry possibly be?* (See also initial reactions to the introduction of infinitesimals by Newton/Leibniz, infinities by Cantor, etc, etc, etc.)